# Need help converting Jquery to Mootools

Tags: jquery, mootools

Could someone please assist me with converting the following Jquery script to the mootools equivalent?

I need to use Mootools to prevent a conflict issue with my Joomla site.

```
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){
        jQuery('div.rj_insertcode a.glossarylink').each(function() {
            jQuery(this).replaceWith(jQuery(this).html());
        });  
        jQuery('.no_glossary a.glossarylink').each(function() {
            jQuery(this).replaceWith(jQuery(this).html());
        });  
    });     
    </script>
    </head>
```

Alternately, it would be appreciated if anyone can recommend how to make the above code compatible with Mootools (I'm fairly new to both languages).

Comment: they are not languages, they are frameworks/toolkits wrapping around a language

Comment: what's the purpose of this script, to get rid of the links and keep their inner html? are you on mootools 1.12 or 1.2x?

Comment: Well , as you are not using the shorthand "$" sign to refer to jQuery , i don't this might cause a conflict with mooTools.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not going to port it over directly, but here are the MooTools equivalents of the used methods:

- `jQuery(document).ready(fn)` → `window.addEvent('domready', fn)` - executes the function when the browser is ready loading the DOM - [docs](http://www.mootools.net/docs/core/Utilities/DOMReady)
- `jQuery(selector)` → `$$(selector)` - returns a collection of elements - [docs](http://www.mootools.net/docs/core/Element/Element#Window%3adollars)
- `collection.each(fn)` → `collection.each(fn)` - iterates over each element - [docs](http://www.mootools.net/docs/core/Types/Array#Array%3aeach)
- `jQuery(this).replaceWith(html)` → `this.replaces(element)` - replaces an element with another one - [docs](http://www.mootools.net/docs/core/Element/Element#Element%3areplaces)

See also the docs which I linked for examples.

Answer (score 2):

for mootools 1.2.5

```
window.addEvent("domready", function(){
    $$('div.rj_insertcode a.glossarylink, .no_glossary a.glossarylink').each(function(el) {
        new Element("span", {
            html: el.get("html")
        }).replaces(el);
    });  
});
```

for 1.12

```
window.addEvent("domready", function(){
    $$('div.rj_insertcode a.glossarylink, .no_glossary a.glossarylink').each(function(el) {
        el.replaceWith(new Element("span").setHTML(el.innerHTML));
    });
```

notice this really wraps it into a span as you can't just convert an element into ... text 
    });